Can you see through a cannonball packing?
More precisely, in a regular sphere packing, either the
HCP or FCC lattice packing,
does there exist a line $L$ disjoint from every sphere,
i.e., not touching any sphere?
So one could "look through" the packing along the line-of-sight $L$.
If the answer is Yes, the next natural question is: What is the clearance
along $L$? To what radius cylinder could $L$ be fattened before touching a sphere?

Now posted to (and answered on) MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/483407/can-you-see-through-a-cannonball-packing
